# Golden Gate Replication condition

Tags: oracle-golden-gate

In goldengate i want all the replications to happen only when a certain condition satisfies else it should wait until the condition satisfies.

Suppose I’m having a Table ‘T’ with only one row and a column ‘Flag’ in it. For every replication happening in the target database i want to make sure it happens only when the value of the ‘Flag’ is ‘A’ else the replication should wait until the value of the ‘Flag ‘ becomes ‘A’.

I’m not sure if it is possible, can you please help me and tell if it is possible and how can i make it possible.

Answer (score 0):

Something like a filter would work for this.

In extract - TABLE schema.T, FILTER (FLAG = 'A');

You should also make sure that any column that is in a filter is also in the redo logs and captured by Extract for faster performance. You may also want to add the FLAG column to the supplemental log group (using ADD TRANDATA can do this) and then use LOGALLSUPCOLS in the Extract too.

Nick

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional filtering in the extract process itself so that you don't have to extract and replicate the ones that are not matching the condition.
You could either use FILTER as mentioned in comment(s) or you could use SQLPREDICATE in your EXTRACT

i.e.

> TABLE schema.T, SQLPREDICATE "WHERE FLAG = 'A'";

Advantage of using SQLPREDICATE is that you can filter the data that you want to extract with complex SQL "WHERE" conditions as well.